# Long links gets broken when arrived to gmail from node.js app

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, nodemailer, html-to-text

I have an html template in the server that I convert to text so I can send him to the user in email.
The problem is that when I use string.link() function for hyperlinks it breaks them in some length.

example: [Google](http://www.google.com/1233423235252452424552525235235345)

Result in the mail: href="http://www.google.com/1233423235252452424552525235235345">Google

Didn't find any reason for that..any help?
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Have you tried to just send the plain HTML, i.e. not converting it into text?

Comment: Hey thank you, editing the question

Comment: @JW_ question edited, any solution?

Comment: As I understand you are sending it as text. You need to send it as HTML in order to get a link that is working. Else the HTML will just be shown as text.